# odoo 10 when i make card swiping on pos i got an error Unknown barcode

Tags: odoo-10

when i had swiping my card on point of sale to make a payment i got this error

1- unknown bar code

2- The Point of Sale could not find any product, client, employee or action associated with the scanned bar code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got that error because at the time of swiping card your pointer is not pointing to the screen. To resolve this error you just need to click on box where you are entering amount for payment, then swipe card.

Comment: is this need  posbox to complete processes

Comment: No posbox is not necessary to complete this process.

Comment: Thanks Kenval but i need to clear some issues: 1 - your pointer is not pointing to the screen 2 - you just need to click on box where you are entering amount for payment

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you want to know ?

Comment: u said "pointer is not pointing to the screen" what exactly this mean, i did't understand. thanks

Comment: Here pointer means, mouse pointer (cursor) is not targeting(selecting) the box of payment. So once you click on payment screen's box of amount, your issue will be resolved.

Comment: ok i will try this. in case of any problem i will back to you . thanks